# React$Node is undefined

Tags: reactjs, eslint, flowtype

[image]

I created new RN project. And this warning showed.
I use Flow and eslint for this project. And I know what `React$Node` means. But I don't know why this warning shows. Because I think `React` already defined it.

This is my `.eslintrc.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier', 'prettier/react', 'prettier/flowtype'],
  plugins: ['react', 'flowtype', 'jsx-a11y', 'import', 'react-native'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']}],
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': [2, {ignorePureComponents: true}],
    'react/forbid-prop-types': [0, {forbid: []}],
    'import/extensions': [1, 'never', {svg: 'always', json: 'always'}],
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [
      'error',
      {
        devDependencies: true,
        optionalDependencies: false,
        peerDependencies: false,
      },
    ],
    semi: ['error', 'never'],
  },
  env: {
    jest: true,
    browser: true,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this into extends. `"plugin:flowtype/recommended"`. So it works!

```js
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
    'prettier/flowtype',
    'plugin:flowtype/recommended',
  ],
  plugins: ['react', 'flowtype', 'jsx-a11y', 'import', 'react-native'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']}],
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': [2, {ignorePureComponents: true}],
    'react/forbid-prop-types': [0, {forbid: []}],
    'import/extensions': [1, 'never', {svg: 'always', json: 'always'}],
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [
      'error',
      {
        devDependencies: true,
        optionalDependencies: false,
        peerDependencies: false,
      },
    ],
    semi: ['error', 'never'],
  },
  env: {
    jest: true,
    browser: true,
  },
}
```

[Recommended Configuration](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#shareable-configurations)

Answer (score 0):

get same error when use

```
const TProps = {
    children: React$Node
}
```

instead of

```
type TProps = {
    children: React$Node
}
```